# Powershell command to copy entire folder and contents to a different folder?

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I have an assignment where I have to write a powershell command on windows server 2019 that copies my documents folder to another folder called backups. my current script looks like this:

```
copy-item C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\ -destination C:Users\Administrator\Backups(get-date format "dd_mm_yyyy--hh_mm_ss")
```

however, when I run the script it creates a folder in my backups folder but it doesn't have anything in it. what should I fix so it has all the files in my documents folder in this backups folder?

Comment: put a * after documents\

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-6

Comment: would you know how to rename the folder when it gets copied to the current date using get-date?

Comment: Capture the Get-Date cmdlet results as a string to rename the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Tested. This code works. Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310293/how-to-copy-content-of-a-folder-to-another-specific-folder-using-powershell

```
[string]$sourceDirectory = "C:\Temp\Random_Folder"

[string]$destinationDirectory = "C:\Users\anyuser\Documents"
Copy-item -Force -Recurse -Verbose $sourceDirectory -Destination $destinationDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing in your script is `-Recurse`

there's also a windows built in tool named "robocopy"
cmdlet goes like this and can be done from powershell and cmd

`robocopy "Path to be copied from" "Path where it goes"`

for better use of this tool, I'd highly recommend taking a look into its man page /?

`robocopy /?`

It can also delete